# Getting dynamic values from neo4j using Spring data

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

```
public interface WayPointRepository extends GraphRepository, NamedIndexRepository, RelationshipOperationsRepository {
    @Query( value = "start point=node:waypoints(\"name:{name1}\") return point", elementClass=WayPoint.class, type=QueryType.Cypher ) 
    public List getWayPointByName(@Param("name1") String name);
}
```

i have a neo4j database with some points stored in it with index "waypoints", i want to get 
some points dynamically after passing some points. for this i have created  placeholder {name1},

but on calling the  getWayPointByName with dynamic param gives me

```
nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'name:{name1}': Encountered " "}" "} "" at line 1, column 11.
Was expecting one of:
    "TO" ...
     ...
     ...
    ] with root cause
org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Encountered " "}" "} "" at line 1, column 11.
Was expecting one of:
    "TO" ...
     ...
     ...
```

`at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.generateParseException(QueryParser.java:1818)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.jj_consume_token(QueryParser.java:1700)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:1507)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:1309)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:1237)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:1226)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:206)`

exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
start point=node:waypoints(name={name1}) return point
```

Within strings there is no parameter substitution happening.