# SpringData/Neo4j: Querying on Fulltext Index causing RuntimeException due to parameters not getting substituted

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Am using Spring Data for Neo4j to create a fulltext index in the model (NodeEntity) class as follows:

```
@Indexed(indexName="descriptionSearchIdx", indexType=IndexType.FULLTEXT)
private String description;
```

Repository class: I am querying it as follows:

```
@Query("START n=node:descriptionSearchIdx('description:*{0}*') RETURN n;")
public List<MyModel> searchMyModelByText(String searchText);
```

However, the parameter substitution seems to fail by giving a RuntimeException.

The query would function just fine if the {0} is replaced with any valid search terms hard coded, but not with the substitution {0} enabled.

**Any clues??**

NOTE: Am using Play framework, so the stack trace would have bits from that as well.

Stack trace:

```
Execution exception[[RuntimeException: org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'description:*{0}*': Encountered " "}" "} "" at line 1, column 15.
Was expecting one of:
    "TO" ...
    <RANGEEX_QUOTED> ...
    <RANGEEX_GOOP> ...
    ]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'description:*{0}*': Encountered " "}" "} "" at line 1, column 15.
Was expecting one of:
    "TO" ...
    <RANGEEX_QUOTED> ...
    <RANGEEX_GOOP> ...

    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.IndexType.query(IndexType.java:307) ~[neo4j-lucene-index-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:251) ~[neo4j-lucene-index-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:263) ~[neo4j-lucene-index-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_0.TransactionBoundQueryContext$NodeOperations.indexQuery(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:169) ~[neo4j-cypher-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.DelegatingOperations.indexQuery(DelegatingQueryContext.scala:116) ~[neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$spi$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$super$indexQuery(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:142) ~[neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'description:*{0}*': Encountered " "}" "} "" at line 1, column 15.
Was expecting one of:
    "TO" ...
    <RANGEEX_QUOTED> ...
    <RANGEEX_GOOP> ...

    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:211) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.IndexType.query(IndexType.java:303) ~[neo4j-lucene-index-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:251) ~[neo4j-lucene-index-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:263) ~[neo4j-lucene-index-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_0.TransactionBoundQueryContext$NodeOperations.indexQuery(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:169) ~[neo4j-cypher-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.DelegatingOperations.indexQuery(DelegatingQueryContext.scala:116) ~[neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Encountered " "}" "} "" at line 1, column 15.
Was expecting one of:
    "TO" ...
    <RANGEEX_QUOTED> ...
    <RANGEEX_GOOP> ...

    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.generateParseException(QueryParser.java:1849) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.jj_consume_token(QueryParser.java:1731) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:1530) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:1319) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:1275) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:1234) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
```

Comment: Hi Sidharth, unfortunately I think that you need to pass in the complete query as the parameter (descriptionSearchIdx({0})), where {0} = 'description:.*whatever.*'

Comment: @John. That works for me, thanks. However was wondering why to hand-construct the {0} part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting dynamic values from neo4j using Spring data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550736/getting-dynamic-values-from-neo4j-using-spring-data)

Answer (score 1):

You should be also be able to use:

```
interface MyModelRepository extends GraphRepository<MyModel> {

   List<MyModel> findByDescriptionContaining(String searchText);
}
```

Which automatically creates the query with the right index and compound lucene query if the field is indexed.